# Cloud Visionで突然の403エラー

Tags: python

Cloud VisionでOCRを使わせていただいているのですが、全くcodeを変更していないにもかかわらず、突然403エラーを吐くようになりました。エラーコードを調べてみると、

```
We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now. See <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Google Help</a> for more information.
```

とあります。確かにCloud Function経由で多数のリクエストを送っていますが、規定のサービス料を支払っていて、これまで一年間ほどエラーが出たことはありません。対処方法などご存じの方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

> See [Google Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640) for more information

は読みましたか？

> Google に自動送信トラフィックとして認識される例
>
> - ロボット、コンピュータ プログラム、自動化サービス、検索スクレーパから送信された検索
> - サイトやページの Google でのランクを判断するソフトウェアを使って Google に送信された検索

と書かれてあります。つまりプログラムから自動送信されることを想定していません。もし人間の手から送信されたリクエストが Cloud Function 経由で送られていることを想定しているのなら、このエラーを検知してユーザーに通知する仕組みを作ってロボットでない証明を行ってもらう工程が必要になるでしょう。

Comment: 文字認識のAPIですから、何らかのプログラムからアクセスするのは自然なことで、それが拒否されるというのは不思議な感じがします。アクセス数も常識的な数（2000アクセス/day程度）です。

Comment: Google には問い合わせましたか？そちらが先ではないでしょうか。